# How can I get a user to break out of a loop via text input?

Tags: python, list, loops

Lets say a teacher wants to add n number of students to a database.

```py
n = 1000
students = dict(input("enter students name and grade. Example 'Student C: '").split()
    for _ in range(n))
print(students)
```

This is fine if we have 1000 students, but what if the teacher wants to finish after 10 students? Is there a way we can input "quit" to break the loop?

Comment: save the `input("")` to a variable and check it, if it's equal to "quit" or whatever then use `break`

Comment: there's no way to break out of a list comprehension, use a loop instead. Then you can check the input and use `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = {}
while True:
    grade = input("enter students name and grade. Example 'Student C: '").split()
    if grade[0] == 'quit':
       break
    else:
        m[grade[0]] = grade[1]


print(m)
```

Comment: This does not solves the questioner's  problem

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer how so ?

Comment: He wants that the user keep entering the data and when the data is quit then exit the loop .

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer It's a different way to solve the same problem of not having 1000 students.

Comment: So you should include in answer that it's a different way

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer its been updated

Answer (score 3):

Rather than embed a generator expression in a single call to `dict`, build your `dict` as you process in the input.

```
n = 1000
students = {}
for _ in range(n):
    x = input("enter students name and grade. Example 'Student C: '")
    if x == "quit":
        break
    # You might want to do more error checking here.
    student, grade = x.split()
    students[student] = grade
```

---

A little more advanced, you can make use of the two-argument form of `iter` (see below) to terminate the loop if `quit` is entered, and use `itertools.islice` to limit the loop to `n` entries.

```
from itertools import islice


n = 1000
students = {}
for x in islice(iter(lambda: input("..."), "quit"), n):
    student, grade = x.split()
    students[student] = grade
```

---

As you might notice, this allows you (ignoring any error checking while splitting the line of input) to go back to your original idea of a generator in a call to `dict`:

```
from itertools import islice


n = 1000
students = dict(x.split() for x in islice(iter(lambda: input("..."), "quit"), n))
```

---

Finally, if you were only using `n` as *a* way to avoid reading input forever, you can omit it, as the user can now enter `quit` any time they like:

```
students = dict(x.split() for x in iter(lambda: input("..."), "quit"))
```

Also, another way to create a zero-argument callable to use as the first argument to `iter` is to use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial


students = dict(x.split() for x in iter(partial(input, "..."), "quit"))
```

---

### What does `iter(x, y)` do?

(The two-argument form of `iter` takes a function to call repeatedly, and produces the return value of that function until the function returns the second argument. `iter(lambda: input("..."), n)` is equivalent to

```
def iter(f, stop):
    while True:
        x = f()
        if x == stop:
            break
        yield x
```

)

### What does `islice(x, y)` do?

This produces a new iterator that returns only the first `y` elements of `x`, if it has more than `y` elements. It is roughly equivalent to

```
def islice(x, y):
    while y:
        yield next(x)
        y -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way. If you are using python 3 use input() function which will capture the entered Stdin text into a string. Match that string with the word "quit" and a conditional if statement. i.e. if string == "quit" then exit() or something similar.

A better way I think would be to ask how many entries are required in the beginning no? rather than constantly entering input in a while loop. Just my 0.2 cents.

Comment: `exit()` will kill the entire script, they should just break out of the loop.

Comment: 'or something similar'.

Comment: `break` and `exit()` are not similar at all, IMHO.

Comment: His intention is to quit. anyway, answers abound.

Comment: No it isn't, his intention is to create a dictionary with all the names entered before typing "quit".

Answer (score 1):

Store the input from user to a variable and check if it is the value is quit or not if it is use break statement to exit the loop or add the input to dictionary.